# Creating a service that updates the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a web application and I need little widgets that should be available from all controllers (i.e. a loading overlay and a sliding drawer). I have created directives with methods to display such behaviour, but you can't inject directives in controllers, that's not how they work.

I know I have to create a service that deals with this, and inject it in both controller and directive, but still can't figure out how to make the communication. The elements that have the directive are unique.

Another option I've considered is to create event listeners in the $rootScope or somewhere else and call $emit from all controllers that might need it, but I feel like the other way is more angular-y

Comment: Can you try to explain with example?

Comment: Shouldn't the directive simply be initialized with an object from the controller scope, and have the controller modify this scoped object to change the way the widget is displayed?

Comment: Yes, you should probably link the view and the service by creating a method in your controller and inject that method in your directive when you place the tag in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Your "widgets" need ng-controller directives. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<div ng-mywidgetdirective ng-controller="mywidgetcontroller"></div>
```